# Event Triggered Workflows

Tags: events, architecture, workflow

I´m writing a software that work to process a set of data that came from use input process it and send an answer to the user.

The flow starts based on a configured API Callthat start a chain of API calls passing the result of each API for the next one until reachs the final output.

The problem is that the chain of calls is configurable by the user in order to process the data before saving it to the database.

Giving you a little example:
I receive data from an API that has the readings from a field sensor, on the arrival of this data I should do the following things:

1. Save the data on the database
2. Process the Data
3. Based on the data and on a configuration that should be made by the user I should get information from a diferent API (the APIs depend on the content of the data)
4. Send the information that I got from the other API to a third which will send it back to the sensor

Do you know any solution that´s capable of doing this kind of work?

Doesn´t mather the language or the framework, since it´s a brand new software we are free to start from the very first step.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am considering that, You have a form where user entering the Data, you are receiving the data, processing it and returning the answer based on the Data and your set of rules.

- If you have a single form, get the data and pass to the API - RESTFul API
- Process the data at server end
- Response to client based on the set of rules of user entered data.
- If you have Multiple form and coming to user one after one then do same.

Hope the process works. if you could clarify the Requirement more specifically then I can draw the Process in more depth.

Comment: Thanks for replying.

Comment: Just explained my use case a little better so you can understand it. I´m looking for is a solution that is capable of triggering APIs calls based on an input.

Comment: You are welcome.
Do you have Form with Fields or only single input each item form user?
-> If Form then once Form submitted then the API will be triggered. 
--> If single Input then on-submit event you can triggered the API calls.